# Why operating with decimals in Rails sometimes returns a integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Take this examples:

#### schema.rb

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "total",                precision: 10, default: "0.0"
```

#### article_controller.rb

```
@article.total = @article.total + (1.1).to_d
@article.total # outputs an integer (1)
```

Why this happens if both values where decimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that I found is to add **scale** to the field, you can generate a migration:

```
class ChangeFieldToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :articles, :total, :decimal, default: 0.0, precision: 10, scale: 2
  end
end
```

With the scale configured the problems was fixed.